# Caller - Caller Saved Registers and Calling Conventions in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, calling-convention, att

I was reading about call conventions in Assembly x86-64 (AT&T) and have few questions:

1. Does the caller need to backup all caller saved regiters even those which the called function won't change? Or we always backup all of them
2. Same question regarding calle
3. I read:

[image]

And didn't understand this point... how is the order related to variable number of arguments? even if we push in same order it will be 100% find in my opinion.

Comment: The caller does not know which registers the callee will change, only which ones it is allowed to change. Yeah the varargs statement is misleading, what it allows is to pass more arguments than what the function expects. Also I always found "pushing in reverse order" misleading, since you are not required to use push and the end result will be in normal order in memory (earlier arguments have lower addresses), the reversing is only due to the push.

Comment: This is a *convention* for an *interface*. In particular, calling conventions allow interoperability of object code compiled at different times, by different compilers and compiler versions, written by different people. Do you need to conform to a calling convention if you're writing trivially small bits of code in assembly by hand? Probably not - unless you want to be able to maintain the code for any length of time while allowing nontrivial modifications. More realistically, a modern compiler can relax the calling convention for functions it doesn't expose to calls from other code.

Answer (score 1):

The term Caller Saves is the same as Scratch and the same as Call Clobbered, which is probably the most descriptive among these terms.

> Does the caller need to backup all caller saved registers even those which the called function won't change? Or we always backup all of them?

The answer to your question depends on what these call clobbered registers are being used for — or in other words, because the values they are holding cannot be guaranteed to be the same after a call, then if these values are important (i.e. used after the call but not otherwise reproducible), then they would have to be preserved.  But if they are not important values they do not have to be preserved.  The caller gets to decide.  (And there is nothing illegal about preserving more call clobbered registers than necessary.)

Typically though, a caller would simply avoid the call clobbered registers for a value that is defined before a call and used after — rather than using a call clobbered register along with a caller saves strategy.

The term callee saves is the same as call preserved, which is probably more descriptive.

As long as all callers & callees observe the same calling convention, then values in the call preserved registers are guaranteed to survive a call without change, so they can be relied upon by the caller.

---

In the early days, computers used heap memory but did not necessarily employ stack memory!  When stacks were added (to support recursion and efficient local variables) there were now two dynamically growable entities, so it was decided that the most effective use of free memory was to put the unused memory (or gap) between the heap and stack, by making the stack grow downwards into the gap (into which the heap grows upwards by traditional).

Since the stack starts high and grows downward by memory address, then pushing parameter in reverse order means that they appear in forwards order in sequential memory addresses.  For calling conventions that pass some parameters in registers in addition to some on the stack, the logic is that the registers represent the bottom of the stack, i.e. the first few parameters (and are as yet unsaved there), though the callee can save them there at the bottom of the stack and achieve a contiguous memory block representing all of the parameters.  This is helpful for varargs implementations, in which callees are not aware of how many actual parameters were passed by any given call, since with varargs, different callers will call with different numbers of parameters.